# Does Firefox Responsive Design Mode have Viewport Zooming disabled by default?

Tags: firefox, devtools, firefox-developer-tools

If this two pages:

- https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/responsive-design/example/default-viewport-zoom/responsive.html
- https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/responsive-design/example/disabled-viewport-zoom/responsive.html

are opened in the Chrome Dev Tools with Device Mode turned on, they look differently. The difference in them is this tag in the head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

However, if I open these pages in Firefox (or in a freshly installed Firefox Developer Edition without any additional plugins) with Responsive Design Mode turned out, they appear the same. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does.
Enter

```
about:config
```

in the address bar and look for the setting

```
dom.meta-viewport.enabled
```

and change it to true. It works but there are some [UI issues in firefox 71 if it is enabled](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1521814).